# getElementsByTagName not working in IE9

Tags: javascript

I want to replace my span content with bold to highlight to user so I fetched tags using getElementsByTagName and replaced with new bold text, its working fine in chrome but not in IE9

```
var span = document.getElementById("testId").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
var newBoldSpan = "<b>" + span + "</b>";
document.getElementById("testId").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML = newBoldSpan;
```

But on IE 9 getElementById  does not return any tags so getting undefined when using getElementsByTagName("a")
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: This is where jQuery is really good :)

Comment: <li class="yui3-widget yui3-treenode yui3-treenode-leaf yui3-treenode-focused" id="product_11998" role="presentation"><a class="yui3-treenode-label" id="yui_3_5_1_6_1487166300117_487" role="treeitem" href="#"><span class="yui3-treenode-label-content">Product code description here</span></a><ul class="yui3-treenode-content" id="yui_3_5_1_199_1487166300117_140"></ul></li>

Comment: Break your first line into three parts and check which part of its actually not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by first using li.getElementsByTagName rather document.getElementById then iterated over it to find my desired element and highlighted by adding bold tag

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByTagName can be known to fail within Internet Explorer if you have any invalid markup such as other tags that are contained within a  tag.

You may want to also take a look at your syntax to ensure that it is correct. Can you include a the relevant html aswell?

EDIT:
So, what I can see there is that your id is wrong, but that would be invalid for both IE and Chrome, so it's probably not the ID you are running in your actual code.

It might help you to break up the code:

```js
var li = document.getElementById("product_11998");
console.log('li', li);
var a = li.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
console.log('a', a);
var span = a.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
console.log('span', span);
var newBoldSpan = "<b>" + span + "</b>";
document.getElementById("product_11998").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML = newBoldSpan;
```

And also check where the code is running. Possibly it is executing in IE before the DOM is rendered for some reason?